# Assume that $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic vector spaces. What does it imply if $V$ and $W$ are not finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

All of the theorems in my textbook in regards to isomorphisms and dual spaces speak specifically about relationships between finite vector spaces.

For example, "Two finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension."

And "Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional, then $V'$ is also finite dimensional and dim$V'$=dim$V$.

I have encountered a problem that seems to conspicuously leave out the normal preface of "assume $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional...". I'm wondering how far I can extend the rules of finite dimensional vector spaces, dual spaces and isomorphisms, and their relationships.

**EDIT:** For example, I believe the following proof would be correct if we are only considering finite vector spaces:

Assume $V'$ and $W'$ are isomorphic, then $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

- dim$V'$ = dim$W'$ = dim$V$ = dim$W$ $\longrightarrow$ $V$ is isomorphic to $W$.

What happens if finite dimension is not mentioned?

Comment: Very difficult at this stage to say what extends and  what does not. It's best if you post the question itself.

Comment: An infinite dimensional space is defined as one that is *not* finite dimensional, so all we can say is : the dimension is infinite. So spaces may very well have the same "dimension" (that is, infinite)  and yet not be isomorphic.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I added more context. I hope that helps. I'm trying to be a little vague so that people are less inclined to do my work for me. It's an assignment for school.

Comment: That is fine, you are just asking a question, we will put it that way. Yes, if finite dimension isn't mentioned, you will land up in trouble with the above statements, they won't even be close to being true.

Comment: It's hard to say with the vagueness. It almost seems like you're given that certain pair(s?) of vector spaces are isomorphic; i.e., $V \cong V' \cong W' \cong W$; in that case, no matter the dimensions, we can conclude $V \cong W$. In general: Given that things *are* isomorphic, you can say a lot. Given only that both are infinite dimensional is much less to go on.

Comment: (But you're correct that simply appealing to the dimensions of the various spaces is *not* enough to conclude $V \cong W$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, two infinite vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension - but you have to appropriately define 'dimension'.  To do this, you'll have to understand [cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number), which are a way of measuring the relative sizes of (possibly infinite) sets.

Every set $S$ has an associated "size", or cardinality, a cardinal number denoted $|S|$ or $\#S$.   A cardinal number may be finite or infinite. Without going into too much detail, the idea is that if two sets can be put in bijection with each other then they must have the same 'size'.  That is, if $S,T$ are sets and $f: S \rightarrow T$ is a bijection, then $|S| = |T|$.  In fact, some infinite cardinals are larger than others.  For example, the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is strictly larger than the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$: $|\mathbb{R}| > |\mathbb{N}|$.

Every vector space has a basis, including infinite-dimensional ones.  In the case of an infinite-dimensional vector space, the dimension can still be defined - we set $\dim(V) = |B|$ for any basis $B$ of $V$.  (To prove this definition is well defined, you need to first show that $|B| = |B'|$ for any bases $B, B'$ of $V$.)  If there is an isomorphism $T: V \rightarrow V'$ between two vector spaces $V$ and $V'$, choose any basis $B$ of $V$; then $B' = T(B)$ is a basis for $V'$ and $T$ is a bijection between $B'$ and $B$.  This shows that $B$ and $B'$ are the same size in the sense of cardinality.

Since some infinite cardinals are larger than others, it is **not** true that all infinite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic.

Note, however, that many things that hold for finite-dimensional vector spaces and linear maps do not hold for infinite-dimensional ones.  For example, linear transformations between isomorphic finite-dimensional vector spaces are injective if and only if they are surjective.  This is not true of infinite-dimensional vector spaces. Infinite-dimensional spaces have isomorphic proper subspaces, etc.

Comment: Your explanation makes good sense. I remember covering cardinality in my undergraduate proof writing class. Unfortunately, it hasn't been mentioned at all in this class, my first graduate linear algebra course. I'm not sure how to apply what you said to answer the assigned question... I think maybe I'm not supposed to provide a proof, and "not necessarily" might be a perfectly acceptable answer. Is there any way to prove that my example is true or false with only what I would have learned in an elementary class?

Comment: I would need to see the question.  If there has not been given a definition of dimension for infinite-dimensional spaces, the question is ill-posed.