# determine if the pair of vector spaces is isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-space-isomorphism

i am considering a number of pairs of vector spaces like the following.

$F^3$ and $P_3(F)$

i think this pair of vector spaces is not isomorphic because $dim(F^3) = 3 \neq dim(P_3(F)) = 4$

i also think that in general whenever two different vector spaces have different dimension, they cannot be isomorphic.

am i correct? thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: To see this, you can prove that a basis is mapped to a basis by a vector space isomorphism.

Comment: And see also the duplicates here, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261408/assume-that-v-and-w-are-isomorphic-vector-spaces-what-does-it-imply-if-v?rq=1), which includes even infinite-dimensional vector spaces.